# How to ensure traffic on ssl port

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to redirect the traffic on non-SSL port 8080 to SSL port 8443( on Tomcat 7.0.67).Here is my configuration in server.xml file

for non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443"
 />
```

and for SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" 
           secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/home/girish/Desktop/keystore/mytomcat.cert" 
               keystorePass="tomcat"
  />
```

and security constraints in web.xml file of my project as

```
 <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>matchstix</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>      
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

my project have only web service (REST API). so i am using the postman-REST-Client to do the CURD operations, its working fine for https.

But How can i ensure that when i uses the non SSL port 8080 it redirect the request to SSL port ?

is there any way by ensuring that from `catalina.out` or any other log files of tomcat ?